# Google Maps draggable marker not work in collapse class bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps, jquery-ui

I want to put a Google Maps draggable marker inside a collapse class bootstrap but it doesn't work. If I put the map outside the collapse class everything just working fine, the problem is just happen when I put the map inside the collapse class.

This is the HTML code:

```
<div class="col-lg-12" >
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree"> Input Map?</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <!--map start-->
                    <div class="col-lg-8" >
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Map</label>
                            <div id="map" class="col-lg-8 tambah-map-canvas"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <label>Coordinat</label><br/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Latitude</label>
                            <input type="text" name="lat" id="lat" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Longitude</label>
                            <input type="text" name="lng" id="lng" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="button" id="reset" value="Reset Location">
                            <br/><br/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--map end-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function updateMarkerPosition(latLng) {
        document.getElementById('lat').value = [latLng.lat()];
        document.getElementById('lng').value = [latLng.lng()];
    }

    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 7,
    scaleControl: true,
      center:  new google.maps.LatLng(-6.175500045712664,106.8272084918824),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
    myOptions);

    var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position : new google.maps.LatLng(-6.175500045712664,106.8272084918824),
    title : 'lokasi',
    map : map,
    draggable : true
    });

    //updateMarkerPosition(latLng);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'drag', function() {
        updateMarkerPosition(marker1.getPosition());
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('reset').onclick= function() {
        var field1= document.getElementById('lng');
        var field2= document.getElementById('lat');
        field1.value= field1.defaultValue;
        field2.value= field2.defaultValue;
    };
</script>
```

Is there anything I miss? What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Create a JSFiddle for better analysis.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see your CSS on the id of `#map` but if it's not set to a specific height (i.e. `400px`) then when you collapse the div, it really won't show.

So the fastest solution would be to set the height of your map to a fixed amount.

Then, regardless if you have draggable markers or not, the map will load on collapse.

Here's a sample: (also, a [jsbin link](http://jsbin.com/duboyig/edit?html,js,output) if needed)

```js
var map;
var center = {
  lat: -34.397,
  lng: 150.644
};

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: center,
    zoom: 8
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: center,
    map: map,
    draggable: true
  });
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 400px; /* Set this to something fixed */
}

/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Simple Map</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="exampleAccordion" data-children=".item">
    <div class="item">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#exampleAccordion" href="#exampleAccordion1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="exampleAccordion1">
      Click to toggle the map
    </a>
      <div id="exampleAccordion1" class="collapse show" role="tabpanel">
        <div id="map"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCD0rWgXRVBa7PgaTWXVp_gU51pgHGviYY&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope that helps!